# Ubuntu 20.04 Cannot Boot Due to Missing Modules

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

When trying to boot up my laptop I'm presented with an error message saying:

"ALERT! UUID=199df2c0-c427-4e87-9edf-b64a88ccb54e does not exist. Dropping to a shell!".

Most other answers for a similar problem involve changing boot or UEFI settings, but the problem is that I cannot change them due to the fact there is no password setup for the UEFI settings menu (I assume there is a factory setup password or something).

I've tried booting from a flash drive I have but every time I try I'm presented with a message saying that Secure Boot forbids booting from hd01 (my flashdrive). I would assume that I could turn off secure boot in the UEFI settings, but again, I'm blocked out because there's no actual password for it (at least to my knowledge). Is there any way I could change my boot settings in the grub menu or anywhere that I would NOT need to go into the UEFI firmware settings?

Comment: This message is telling you a disk partition with that unique ID (UUID) cannot be found, meaning someone may have deleted a partition, OR you have failing disk.  It's usually a result of mistakes made during the last working session (*eg. partition deleted*) OR hardware issues you should explore and they are best explored using uEFI/Settings or *live* media and not booting the system (you want the disk not in used for exploration).  *From the live media you could perform file-system checks, if errors are found & corrected you can expect normal boot after that too*

Comment: Any chance its 5.15.0-53 kernel ? Try to revert to previous kernel on Advanced Options. I believe there is a bug, see if this matches with you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1998266